# Photoshop tracking and kerning: what do the number values mean?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, kerning, units

Working on a site design where I'm trying to translate a tracking value of "100" to the CSS `letter-spacing` property.

When I specify a tracking value of "100", what am I saying? Definitely doesn't seem like percent or pixels.

I tend to eyeball to get what I want, but I'd rather run a conversion and not have to think about it if that's possible.

Comment: Hi Brendan, I found this relevant question asked on Stackoverflow [How to calculate CSS letter-spacing v.s. “tracking” in typography?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760784/how-to-calculate-css-letter-spacing-v-s-tracking-in-typography)

Comment: May or may not be correct, but doesn't cite any sources. Good find though! Appreciate you sharing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers given in the question linked to in AndrewH’s comment are correct.

As noted on [this Photoshop help page](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/line-character-spacing.html):<sup>1</sup>

> Tracking and kerning are both measured in **1/1000 em**, a unit of measure that is relative to the current type size. In a 6‑point font, 1 em equals 6 points; in a 10‑point font, 1 em equals 10 points. Kerning and tracking are strictly proportional to the current type size.

In other words, you can achieve the same CSS letter-spacing by dividing the Photoshop tracking value by 1,000 and using the quotient, in ems, as the letter-spacing value.

<sup><sup>1</sup> The page linked to is for Photoshop, but the same holds true for all other Adobe products. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_(typography)), Quark has 1/200 em as its base unit.</sup>

Comment: Adding to this answer; if you use a letter spacing of 20 in InDesign/Illustrator/Photoshop that translates to CSS best using `letter-spacing: calc(20rem/1000)`

Comment: @Kalaschnik Just saw your comment now – shouldn’t that calculation be using `em`s rather than `rem`s? If the text has a size of `3rem`, letter-spacing based on a `rem` calculation would be three times less than you were expecting.